# cant call curl from python3

Tags: python-3.x, curl

I am trying to call this `curl` from `python3`. This, from `bash`, is working fine.

```
curl -LH "Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex" http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.126802
```

yielding the expected result:

```
 @article{Chang_2016, title={Observation of the Quantum Anomalous Hall Insulator to Anderson Insulator Quantum Phase Transition and its Scaling Behavior}, volume={117}, ISSN={1079-7114}, url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.126802}, DOI={10.1103/physrevlett.117.126802}, number={12}, journal={Physical Review Letters}, publisher={American Physical Society (APS)}, author={Chang, Cui-Zu and Zhao, Weiwei and Li, Jian and Jain, J. K. and Liu, Chaoxing and Moodera, Jagadeesh S. and Chan, Moses H. W.}, year={2016}, month={Sep}}
```

in python3, I am doing:

```
import subprocess
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.126802"
try:
    subprocess.call(["curl", "-LH", '"Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex"', doi])
except ExplicitException:
    print("DOI is not available")
    self.Messages.on_warn_clicked("DOI is not given",
                                  "Search google instead")
```

which is giving error:

```
<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>
```

whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 problems here:

1. don't quote your arguments in `subprocess`, it already does that for you when necessary, since you pass the arguments and not the unsplitted command line (good practice, keep it on, but drop the unneccessary quoting).
2. then, `subprocess.call` does not allow to parse/store the output in python, which is problematic for number 3:
3. and last: your site answers with rubbish HTML (java stacktrace) randomly. This explains why you're getting different output in python, but you can get it in bash as well.

#### Problem #1

```
subprocess.call(["curl", "-LH", '"Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex"', doi])
```

should be

```
subprocess.call(["curl", "-LH", 'Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex', doi])
```

Else, quotes are applied twice and your `Accept: xxx` argument has quotes around it, which is unexpected by `curl`

demo of the non-working quote part:

```
import subprocess,os
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.126802"

#### this is wrong because of the quoting ####
p = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "-LH", '"Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex"', doi],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
[output,error] = p.communicate()
print(output)
```

result:

```
b' some stats then ... <html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>\nYour browser sent an invalid request.\n</body></html>\n\r\n'
```

#### Problems #2 and #3

I have implemented a retry mechanism which parses the output and retries until correct output is found:

```
import subprocess,os,sys
doi = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.126802"

while True:
    p = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "-LH", 'Accept: text/bibliography; style=bibtex', doi],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    [output,error] = p.communicate()
    output = output.decode("latin-1")
    if "java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run" in output:
        # site crashed when responding: junk HTML output: retry
        sys.stderr.write("Wrong answer: retrying\n")
    else:
        print(output)
        break
```

result:

```
Wrong answer: retrying   <==== here the site throwed a big HTML exception output
 @article{Chang_2016, title={Observation of the Quantum Anomalous Hall Insulator to Anderson Insulator Quantum Phase Transition and its Scaling Behavior}, volume={117}, ISSN={1079-7114}, url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.126802}, DOI={10.1103/physrevlett.117.126802}, number={12}, journal={Physical Review Letters}, publisher={American Physical Society (APS)}, author={Chang, Cui-Zu and Zhao, Weiwei and Li, Jian and Jain, J.âK. and Liu, Chaoxing and Moodera, Jagadeesh S. and Chan, Moses H.âW.}, year={2016}, month={Sep}}
```

So it works, it's just a site problem, but with my python wrapper you are able to re-submit the request until it yields the proper answer.

Comment: I did this as the original curl  has Accept :*** inside curl. So, how you want to represent "" around Accept? I tried that, and not working. Is this working for you? (i mean yielding the same result as normal curl?) For me , its like normal curl, writing whole html in stdout

Comment: do you understand the difference? if you open your exemple in terminal, you will write `notepad foo.txt`., not as `notepad "foo.txt"`. so, your 2nd example is giving invalid filename. for my case, "Accept:**" is in actual command.

Comment: now this works. I tested. and I was right about the quotes, everything. So now you can upvote and accept :)

Comment: `"Accept:**"` is not in your command `Accept:**` is. bash removes the quote to pass arguments. So the python program has to respect the same logic.

Comment: curl is command, Accept:*** is options(with/withoout quote)...but anyway, without quote, it gives the full html (see my first reply to you). It is not same as the result from bash's curl, right?

Comment: I ran it several times from command line: sometimes it outputs a lot of html garbage and sometimes it works. I get the same exact behaviour from python. The site must have a timeout problem whatever, but it's not python (or my) fault. However, I can implement a retry mechanism.